# Passing ID Of Dynamic Javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to pass the element itself, or id. How can I make this work?

```
onclick="addYes(this)"
```

---

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  tempTable+= '<tr>'+
    '<td  class="cust-data-row"style="height:40px;width:40%;">'+
    data[i].service+
    '</td>'+
    '</td>'+ 
    '<td  class="cust-data-row-yes" style="height:40px;width:10%;  id="rec_btn_yes_' +i+'"  onclick="addYes(this)" >'+
    'Yes'+
    '</td>'+
    '</tr>';            
}

function addYes(button){
  //shows nothing:
  alert(button.id); 
  //not working:
  document.getElementById(button.id).addClass("clicked_yes");
  //unrecognized method:
  button.addClass("clicked_yes");
}
```

Comment: `onclick="addYes(this)"` should definitely work, to add class just use `button.classList.add('clicked_yes')` as button is a DOM element it does't have the `addClass()` method

Comment: in the `addYes` method you can get the id like this `var id = $(button).attr("id")`

Comment: `document.getElementById(button.id).addClass("clicked_yes");` when you get it working, that line is not valid

Comment: @Satpal worked for me thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Just small change in `addClass()` code and everything works fine:-***

Working snippet:-

```js
function addYes(button){
  alert(button.id); 
  $("#"+button.id).addClass("clicked_yes");
}
```

```css
.clicked_yes{
  color:red;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="abc" onclick="addYes(this)">click pls!</button>
```

Comment: I like this answer because this is exactly the css I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in this snippet with *pure* javascript:

```js
var tempTable = "<button id='theID' onclick='addYes(this)'>retrieve id</button>";

document.body.innerHTML += tempTable;

function addYes(button){
alert(button.id); 
//As @SatPal commented
button.classList.add("clicked_yes");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all

```
document.getElementById(button.id)
```

will gives you button which is already you have.

second you should apss your element to jquery to use thats addClass method

```
$(button).addClass("someclass");
```

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you can do as follow:

```html
$("#Your_button").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("clicked_yes");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look. It May help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    var $tr = '<tr>'+
    '<td  class="cust-data-row"style="height:40px;width:40%;">'+
    i +
    '</td>'+
    '</td>'+ 
    '<td  class="cust-data-row-yes" style="height:40px;width:10%;" id="rec_btn_yes_' +i+'" onclick="addYes(this);" >'+
    'Yes_'+ i +
    '</td>'+
    '</tr>';
    $("#t_body").append($tr);
}
});

function addYes(button){
  //shows nothing:
  console.log(button);
  alert(button.id);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
            <tbody id="t_body">
                
            </tbody>
</table>
```